# Polynomial iterates with finite/infinite orbits

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-dynamics

Given a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ and a point $x_0\in\mathbb{C}$ I am trying to decide if the set $\{x_0,x_1=f(x_0),x_2=f(x_1),\cdots\}$ is finite or infinite.

My general strategy is to iterate $f$ until the absolute value is large enough that the orbit must be infinite, or until I detect a loop.

So far I have been able to prove that once the value exceeds $k/|a_n|$ the orbit must be infinite, where $a_n$ is the leading coefficient and k is the sum of the absolute values of the other coefficients. (Where this is not well-defined the problem is easy.)

So my questions are: is the general strategy a good one? Can my general bound be improved -- indeed, is it correct?

I would be interested also in the restriction to integer polynomials and values.

Comment: How can $k/|a_n|$ not be well-defined?

Comment: It is also worth noting that this strategy will not always be successful: consider $f(x)=x^2$, $x_0=e^{\alpha i \pi}$ for some irrational $\alpha$. This orbit is infinite but bounded.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Does the strategy always work over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? Do you have a strategy that works over $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

Comment: When you ask whether the strategy works over $\mathbb Z[x]$, are you restricting $x_0$ to be in $\mathbb Z$? Otherwise my counterexample still applies. Unfortunately I don't know a general strategy.

Comment: @AlexBecker: Yes, I meant with $x_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ as well.

Comment: If I may add one more comment: I have read from Professor Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems" and I suspect it will be very relevant to your question. For instance, chapter 1 is an introduction to Classical Dynamics (on $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$) which directly relates to your original problem and I can see several potentially useful ideas. For example, Riemann-Hurwitz formula tells you how many ramified point there are.

Comment: Professor Silverman also has notes for Arizona Winter school, which can be found [here](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2010/2010SilvermanNotes.pdf). It also contains the introduction to classical dynamics.

Comment: @YongHaoNg: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Height bounds of preperiodic points**
If the set is finite, then $x_0$ is a preperoidic point so that
$$f^{n+m}(x_0)=f^m(x_0)$$
for some $m,n\in \Bbb Z$. Then $f^m(x_0)$ is a periodic point.

[Northcott's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_dynamics) says that if $f$ is rational and has degree $\geq 2$, then the number of algebraic preperiodic points is finite. Therefore the height strategy should always work for your polynomial case, or you can use any type of counting function. The bound computation is typically done via the equation
$$h(f(\beta))=d\cdot h(\beta)+C,$$
where $h$ is the absolute logarithmic height 
$$h\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\log(\max\{|a|,|b|\}) \text{ for }\frac{a}{b}\in\Bbb Q$$
and $C$ is a constant dependent only on $f$. So once $h(\beta)$ is sufficiently large, its iterates grows unbounded. i.e. when $h(\beta)> |C|$: 
$$h(f(\beta))-h(\beta)=d\cdot h(\beta)-h(\beta)+C\geq 2h(\beta)-h(\beta)+C=h(\beta)+C>0$$
so that it cannot be a preperiodic point.

It sounds like what you are describing to find the bound is similar, since it depends only on $f$. I am not so sure what happens when $x_0$ is non-algebraic, but I guess you can try to derive a similar equation for some cases, possibly using some variant of $h$. I have no idea what happens for other types of functions $f$.

---

**2. Reduction mod $p$**
For periodic points, you can consider reduction mod $p$ when it applies. For example, suppose $f\in \Bbb Q(z)$, then we have the following:

> Let $f\in \Bbb Q(z)$ be a rational function of degree $d\geq 2$ and let $p$ be the smallest primes for which $f(z)$ has good reduction. Suppose $x_0\in \Bbb P^1(\Bbb Q)$ is a periodic point for $f$ of exact period $n$. Then
>   $$n\leq p^3-p$$
>   If $p\geq 5$, then we can reduce this to $n\leq p^2-1$.

Which implies that we only have to test at most $p^3-p$ times. Furthermore, $f$ must have good reduction somewhere so such $n$ can always be found. This result can also be extended to Number fields, so that you can consider $f\in \overline{\Bbb Q}(z)$ and $x_0\in \overline {\Bbb Q}$.

However, to check for preperiodic points one must estimate the maximum value of $m$ as above. I seem to recall some results for this, but unfortunately I have forgotten. You might want to ask for references in Mathoverflow if you are interested.

Otherwise, this trivially applies for $f\in\Bbb Z[x]$ and $x_0\in \Bbb Z$.

---

**3. Linear conjugation**
Let $g(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}\in \Bbb C(z)$ and define 
$$f^g(z)=(g^{-1}\circ f\circ g)(z)$$
Then we can show that
$$(f^g)^n=(g^{-1}\circ f\circ g)^n=g^{-1}\circ f^n\circ g=(f^n)^g$$
Now if $x_0$ is a preperiodic point for $f$ of period $n$, then $g^{-1}(x_0)$ is a preperiodic point for $f^g$ of period $n$.

Let $g(z)=z+x_0$. Then testing whether $x_0$ is preperiodic for $f$ is the same as testing whether
$$g^{-1}(x_0)=0$$ 
is preperiodic for 
$$(f^g)(z)=f(z+x_0)-x_0.$$
This may make it easier for some analysis. For instance, if you know all preperiodic points for $f$ (fixed) then you know all preperiodic points for any $f^g$.

---

**4. Integral points**
Lastly, if you are considering number of integers in orbit, then it is known to be finite when $f\in \Bbb Q(x)$ and $x_0\in \Bbb Q$. i.e. let $\varphi(x_0)=\{f^i(x_0): i\geq 0\}$ then
$$\varphi(x_0)\cap\Bbb Z<\infty$$